# VPN Client in OpenSUSE

Tags: opensuse, vpn, pptp, pppd

So I've been pulling my hair this weekend. I've been trying to connect to a VPN server. I could do it successfully at my office using Windows, but I can't do it in my house using OpenSUSE. Here's the setup in my Linux box :

```
# This module isn't loaded initially
modprobe nf_conntrack_pptp
pptpsetup --create my_vpn --server xxx.xx.xxx.xx --username xxx  --password xxx
pppd call my_vpn debug nodetach
```

And the results are the following:

```
using channel 6
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/4
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xac5d988f> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <auth chap MS-v2> <mru 1460> <magic 0x72d37196>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <auth chap MS-v2> <mru 1460> <magic 0x72d37196>]
rcvd [LCP ConfRej id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 <magic 0xac5d988f>]
rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x2 <magic 0xac5d988f>]
sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x0 magic=0xac5d988f]
rcvd [CHAP Challenge id=0x1 <96a56e74b0a9c972625e5b2a6cfa7ff3>, name = "PS-RTR-INT@DC-CYBERCSF"]
added response cache entry 0
sent [CHAP Response id=0x1 <6878d2f9bafc93c3fd22d7ef83a17cea000000000000000053ed1f4039642a8acec3150b3168abc02cbfa9368595c2a900>, name = "imam"]
rcvd [LCP EchoRep id=0x0 magic=0x72d37196]
rcvd [CHAP Success id=0x1 "S=FB862D3ADF2E8883281F43948FDAF07A06F71780"]
response found in cache (entry 0)
CHAP authentication succeeded
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 20.20.20.1>]
sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x1 <addr 20.20.20.1>]
rcvd [proto=0x8281] 01 01 00 04
Unsupported protocol 'MPLSCP' (0x8281) received
sent [LCP ProtRej id=0x3 82 81 01 01 00 04]
rcvd [IPCP ConfRej id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <addr 0.0.0.0>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x2 <addr 20.20.20.10>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x3 <addr 20.20.20.10>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfAck id=0x3 <addr 20.20.20.10>]
local  IP address 20.20.20.10
remote IP address 20.20.20.1
Terminating connection due to lack of activity.
Connect time 45.9 minutes.
Sent 12744 bytes, received 1344 bytes.
sent [LCP TermReq id=0x4 "Link inactive"]
rcvd [LCP TermAck id=0x4]
Connection terminated.
tcflush failed: Input/output error
Script pptp xxx.xx.xx.xx --nolaunchpppd finished (pid 4616), status = 0x0
```

As you can see, the connection is terminated due to lack of activity.
The local IP address (20.20.20.10) refers to my computer obviously and I can use it normally, but the remote one (20.20.20.1) still not usable.

Is there anything wrong in my setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand, but :

```
modprobe nf_conntrack_pptp
```

and opening VPN via the GUI, instead of terminal, does the job :-/